# Merge multiple dataframes given within a foreach to one dataframe - Scala spark

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, foreach

I have two csv files like below.

```
a.csv

ID,Name,Age,Subject
1,Arun,23,English
2,Melan,22,IT

b.csv 

ID,Name,Department_ID,Age,Subject
3,Kumar,004,21,Science
4,Sagar,008,20,IT
```

As you can see those file structures are different. I want `ID` and `Subject` columns only. So I list the path to files and do the followings.

```
val cols = List("ID", "Subject")

val file_path = List("path to a.csv", "path to b.csv") 

file_path.foreach(path => {

      val df =
        spark
          .read
          .option( "header", "true" )
          .option( "delimiter", "," )
          .csv(path )
          .select(cols.head, cols.tail: _*)

      df.show()
      df.count()

    })
```

1st dataframe

```
## +---+--------+
## |ID|Subject  |
## +--+---------+
## | 1|  English|
## | 2|       IT|
## +--+---------+
```

2nd Dataframe

```
##+---+---------+
## |ID|Subject  |
## +--+---------+
## | 3|  Science|
## | 4|       IT|
## +--+---------+
```

But I need one dataframe by merging those two dataframes. Like below,

```
## +---+--------+
## |ID|Subject  |
## +--+---------+
## | 1|  English|
## | 2|       IT|
## | 3|  Science|
## | 4|       IT|
## +--+---------+
```

Is there any way to do that? I don't want to write those two dataframes to files and read them as one.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map` & `reduce` instead of `foreach` method to achieve this.

Please check below

```
scala> val dfr = spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true")
dfr: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader = org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader@cd6ccda

scala> val paths = List("/tmp/data/da.csv","/tmp/data/db.csv")
paths: List[String] = List(/tmp/data/da.csv, /tmp/data/db.csv)

scala> val columns = List("id","subject").map(c => col(c))
columns: List[org.apache.spark.sql.Column] = List(id, subject)

scala> spark.time { paths.map(path => dfr.load(path).select(columns:_*)).reduce(_ union _).show(false) }
+---+-------+
|id |subject|
+---+-------+
|1  |English|
|2  |IT     |
|3  |Science|
|4  |IT     |
+---+-------+

Time taken: 247 ms

scala>
```

`Edit` As both files has different schemas, loading all files at once will give you wrong result, Please check below.

```
scala> val da = spark.read.option("header","true").csv("/tmp/data/da.csv")
da: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: string, name: string ... 2 more fields]

scala> da.show(false)
+---+-----+---+-------+
|id |name |age|subject|
+---+-----+---+-------+
|1  |Arun |23 |English|
|2  |Melan|22 |IT     |
+---+-----+---+-------+


scala> val db = spark.read.option("header","true").csv("/tmp/data/db.csv")
db: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: string, name: string ... 3 more fields]

scala> db.show(false)
+---+-----+-------------+---+-------+
|id |name |department_id|age|subject|
+---+-----+-------------+---+-------+
|3  |Kumar|004          |21 |Science|
|4  |Sagar|008          |20 |IT     |
+---+-----+-------------+---+-------+


scala> val paths = List("/tmp/data/da.csv","/tmp/data/db.csv")
paths: List[String] = List(/tmp/data/da.csv, /tmp/data/db.csv)

scala> val columns = List("id","subject").map(c => col(c))
columns: List[org.apache.spark.sql.Column] = List(id, subject)

scala> spark.read.option("header", "true" ).option("delimiter", "," ).csv(paths: _* ).select(columns:_*).show(false)
20/04/29 18:35:07 WARN CSVDataSource: CSV header does not conform to the schema.
 Header: id,
 Schema: id, subject
Expected: subject but found:
CSV file: file:///tmp/data/da.csv
+---+-------+
|id |subject|
+---+-------+
|3  |Science|
|4  |IT     |
|1  |null   |
|2  |null   |
+---+-------+

scala> spark.read.option("header", "true" ).option("delimiter", "," ).csv(paths: _* ).select("id","name").show(false) // common columns from both fiels - id,name
+---+-----+
|id |name |
+---+-----+
|3  |Kumar|
|4  |Sagar|
|1  |Arun |
|2  |Melan|
+---+-----+

scala> spark.read.option("header", "true" ).option("delimiter", "," ).csv(paths: _* ).select("id","name","age").show(false) // file-1 has - id,name,age, file-2 has - id,name,department_id,age , in this age came after department_id
20/04/29 18:43:53 WARN CSVDataSource: CSV header does not conform to the schema.
 Header: id, name, subject
 Schema: id, name, age
Expected: age but found: subject
CSV file: file:///tmp/data/da.csv
+---+-----+-------+
|id |name |age    |
+---+-----+-------+
|3  |Kumar|21     |
|4  |Sagar|20     |
|1  |Arun |English|
|2  |Melan|IT     |
+---+-----+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Spark Dataframe has inbuilt feature of loading from multiple files at once.
I think instead of loading them individually and then joining them you can just load them in a single call as below.

```
object LoadJoinDataframe {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val cols = List("ID", "Subject")

    val file_path = List("path to a.csv", "path to b.csv")


    val spark = Constant.getSparkSess
    val df = spark
      .read
      .option( "header", "true" )
      .option( "delimiter", "," )
      .csv(file_path: _* )
      .select(cols.head, cols.tail: _*)
    df.show()
    df.count()

  }

}
```